How to change taskbar size in Windows 11?
How to change taskbar size in Windows 11 ? From what I see, there used to be an option but they removed it. All articles on the internet (they probably copy from each other) say to go to:
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
in registry and add TaskbarSi, which I did, and it doesn't do anything. I tried values 0 and 1 and rebooted every time.

You can probably adjust the text size if you were looking to have larger elements etc but i don't think w11 has any option to customize the size.

What version of Windows 11 are you running? I am finding articles that hint the size of the Taskbar should be adjustable within Settings but since I am running 23H2 I can confirm that is not the case. Which suggest TaskbarSi is only applicable to 24H2+

I just installed it. Version 10.0.22631 build 22631
